# grep multiple words in a file and write the output to a html file on a newline

Tags: html, bash, grep

I wrote a command which greps for multiple words in a file and writes the output to a HTML file.
It is successful. But i get all the grep output on a single line...

I need the output for each grepped word on a new line. Please suggest...

My Current output is :

```
Label: XXX Issued by: XXX Subject: XXXX Valid: XXXXXXX
```

I need my output like this:

```
Label: XXX
Issued by: XXX
Subject: XXXX
Valid: XXXXXXX
```

My grep command is:

```
$IHS_BIN/gskcmd -cert -details -label $lbl -db $line -stashed | grep -w 'Label:\|Subject:\|Issued by:\|Valid:' >> "example.html"
```

Comment: you can either use <pre></pre> pair to place your lines into this block or add <br> to the end of each line by sed -r 's/^(.*)$/\1<br>/'

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most elegant solution but it should work.

```
grep -w 'Label:\|Subject:\|Issued by:\|Valid:' | awk '{ print $1 $2 "<br>" }{print $3 " " $4 $5"<br>"}{print $6 $7"<br>"}{print $8 $9 "<br>"}' >> output.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- There is a whitespace between `:` and the string `XXX`.
- The string `XXX` does not contain whitespaces.

Then how about:

```
grep -oE 'Label: +[^ ]+|Subject: +[^ ]+|Issued by: +[^ ]+|Valid: +[^ ]+'
```